# LEFT JOIN - Sort and Group

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, left-join, grouping

I get only one row of the elements and the matching categories.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT lt_category.id, lt_category.title, lt_category_elements.category_id, lt_category_elements.title as elementitle, lt_category_elements.text  

FROM lt_category

LEFT JOIN lt_category_elements ON lt_category.id = lt_category_elements.category_id");
```

**category 1**

- element1 (is there)
- element 2,3,4,5 (is missing) etc.

**category 2**

- element1 (is there)
- element 2,3,4,5 (is missing) etc.

**category 3**

- element1 (is there)
- element 2,3,4,5 (is missing) etc.

---

Here is my table structure:

```
+------------------------+
| lt_category_elements   |
+------------------------+
| id                     |
| category_id            |
| title                  |
| text                   |
| rel_code               |
| created                |
+------------------------+

+------------------------+
| lt_category            |
+------------------------+
| id                     |
| title                  |
| text                   |
| rel_code               |
| created                |
+------------------------+
```

---

How do I get the missing elements under a single category?

[image: output]

but I need: 
[image]

here is my output code:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    ?>
                        <div class="playerrow">     
                            <span class="category"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></span>
                            <span class="category"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you show of  your table structure for both?

Comment: Something like: `RIGHT JOIN lt_category_elements ON lt_category.id = lt_category_elements.category_id WHERE lt_category_elements.id IS NULL` will get where the elements are missing, but not where they're not ... if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Ranjith, sure. :) i added it.

Comment: so change you output? why do you compare image of screenshot with the html page rendered with plain text? show us the code you use to output that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch tables left <-> right:

```
SELECT lt_category.title, 
       lt_category_elements.category_id, 
       lt_category_elements.title as elementitle, 
       lt_category_elements.text  

FROM lt_category_elements 

LEFT JOIN lt_category
ON lt_category.id = lt_category_elements.category_id
ORDER BY lt_category_elements.category_id, lt_category_elements.id
```

and here is your php output:

```
$curCat = '';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($curCat !== $row['category_id']) {
        if ($curCat !== '')
            echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="playerrow">';
        echo '<span class="category">'.$row['title'].'</span>';
    }
    echo '<span class="category">'.$row['text'].'</span>';
    $curCat = $row['category_id'];
 } 
if ($curCat !== '')
   echo '</div>';
```

Comment: then its: category 1 -> element2. category 1 -> element2. but i want to have category 1 -> element1 -> element2. category 2 -> element1 -> element2 etc..

Comment: you are little bit confused :-) show the expected result in TABLE in your post please. So if you want to concatenate several fields - that is one thing. if you want to generate as many fields (5*3) as you have elements in each category - that is another thing.

Comment: sorry. :) i added my result as picture in my post.

Comment: is it your expected result? I've asked you to show the expected TABLE. because sql always return rows(table). so what is your expected SQL response? how many rows SQL must return to you??

Comment: hi alex, i just need two rows - title and text. i edited my post.

Comment: you are welcome. just try to get an idea : you've got 10 or 15 rows from SQL not 2.